# Is there any way to checkout another branch readily in git?

Tags: git

I'm working on a web project right now.
There are several branches; develop branch for debugging, feature branches for new features, etc.
The QA tester needs to test on both branches at the same time, so programmers have to switch branches when testers tell us to, and this is too bothering.
Is there any way to switch branches readily?

Comment: Try `git worktree`, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree. It allows you to checkout multiple revisions to separated folders.

Comment: *checkout multiple revisions to separated folders* Thus trading disk space for speed and convenience of switching branches with `cd` instead of `git checkout`.

Comment: `git worktree` as @ElpieKay told you is the best way to do it. A shame he didn't propose it as an answer...

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks @ElpieKay !

Answer (score 1):

**To speed up working tree updating**

As ElpieKay* and phd are suggesting in comments up above, a good way to avoid having to wait loading the whole working tree each time you need to check anything on another branch, is [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

Basically, with :

```
git worktree add any/chosen/path
```

...you designate this given path as the base directory for an additional worktree, ready to host another branch, while another is checked out in your main tree. *(not limited to two of course, check the linked above doc for all details)*

---

**To ease typing**

In case you have to switch between **two branches** on a regular basis, one shortcut will be very convenient :

```
# check out the previously checked out branch
git checkout -
```

So when you switch back-and-forth between your 2 branches, at start you

```
git checkout feature
git checkout develop
```

and after that each `git checkout -` just toggles between the 2. (Bonus point for using just the "up" key once or a few times since you need the same line each time)

Let alone the fact that most users end up aliasing `checkout` to some one or two-letter variant, so that it's just the extremely short :

```
git co -
```

---

* *(Hey ElpieKay, you deserve any rep** on this part of the answer, which is the most important, so write an answer and I'll erase the part, that's only fair)*

** *(...not to say that MUCH rep has been gained for now on this answer but still ;-)*

Comment: For what it's worth, `git worktree` can also be a pain in the a**--it doesn't like having two worktrees point to the same branch.  I find that disappointing in that it sometimes kills my workflow.  YMMV. :-)

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I agree. I never had a context in which the benefits (worktree updating times) actually meet or outweigh the costs (disk space and potential mistakes). But it could very well be that bigger repos give another ratio...